# Running command multiple times and trigger report on failure

Tags: shell-script, error-handling

I am trying to run the "make" command on my project 100 times. But, obviously I wouldn't be monitoring the results but I would like to know when the build fails.

How would I go about making it trigger a notification or a mail or a report when the build failed ?

I am doing this to run "make" 100 times

```
    for run in {1..100}
    do
    make
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to happen every time `make` fails, you can call

```
make || mail ...
```

Or, if you're just interested in the number of failures, record the exit status of `make` in an associative array:

```
#! /bin/bash
declare -A exits

for run in {1..100} ; do
    make
    (( exits[$?]++ ))
done

echo Code Number
for code in "${!exits[@]}" ; do
    echo $code ${exits[$code]}
done
```

Comment: I get this. make.sh: line 2: declare: -A: invalid option  declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]   So after it runs 100 times, it tells me how many time it had failed ?

Comment: @Anirudh: It should. What's your bash version? It should work without `declare` on older versions, too.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0) not sure what the problem is

Comment: @Anirudh: How do you run the script?

Comment: sh make.sh   after copying your code into make.sh file. Isn't that how it was supposed to be run ?

Comment: @Anirudh: No, `sh` is not `bash`.

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The following script could notify on success or failure. You could implement mail_notification or other easily?

Perhaps, you have to take a look at the concept of [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) for a more robust solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo_notification() {
  echo "$(date +%Y%m%d:%H:%m:%S) : compilation failed"
}

no_notification() {
  true
}

for run in {1..100} ; do
  make && no_notification || echo_notification 
done
```

If you want to be notify only on the first failure, you could use `set -e` in bash for exiting on failure in a shell script.